# What is the proportion of table from this picture?

Tags: stereographic-projections

I have this picture and I know his `height = 75cm` Do you know how to find out its proportion like width and lenght using perspective projection?
[image]

Comment: The picture almost fits my screen which is nowhere near $75\text{ cm }$ in height.

Comment: @GitGud: I think the real table is supposed to be $75$cm high

Comment: Yes ist hight of real table.

Comment: I think it should take into account all abberations and distortions introduced by the fact that the camera lens is spherical, not perfect, etc. The image is neither an isometry, apparently, nor it preserves parallel lines.